# Include source package and dependency only for a profile with Spring Boot maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In a `Spring Boot` based project of mine I want to create two different builds from the same project.

The decision on which build is generated should come from a `maven` profile.

I want to create one build (full) which includes a certain folder `src/main/java/com/example/demo/full` and a certain dependency, and a second build (`default` or `light`) build which does not include them.

Including the dependencies for build `full` works, but I don't know how to make sure the folder `src/main/java/com/example/demo/full` is only compiled for the `full` build.

Here my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>full</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                    <version>3.16</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

How can I manage to have the mentioned source-folder only compiled for profile `full`?

Comment: I would put the java packages which should be compiled only in on maven profile into a seperate source folder `scr/full-profile/java.....` and include it only in the specific profile.

Comment: Sounds good @matthias, but how to achieve this "inclusion" only for a specifc profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second src folder like `scr\foo` and then add a profile in maven configure this src folder.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<build>
    ...
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>extraSource</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/foo/</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here the source folder is added using the [Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin for maven. As it is embedded in the build section of the [specific profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), it is only active while executing maven with this profile (see the activation section)

Answer (score 0):

there are problem with disabling one of your maven-source-plugin if this dependency is a part of parent which you cant not give ID to, ill recomend to use phase none with this code to one of your pom.xml files that will disable this.

I also recommend to use command: mvn -Prelease-profile help:effective-pom
to print if you have two of dependencies maven-source-plugin in your code, if yes, disable one of them with this code below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```